# what is the way to check whether excel cell is locked or not?

Tags: excel, cell, locked

How to Check if a particluar cell in that range is locked,

I am posting the small snippet of my code, Please suggestme , the better way of writing to cell if the cell is not locked.

if (reader.HasRows) { minRow = 0; minCol = 0;

```
                                // Process each result in the result set
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    // Create an array big enough to hold the column values
                                    object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];

                                    // Add the array to the ArrayList
                                    rowList.Add(values);

                                    // Get the column values into the array
                                    reader.GetValues(values);

                                    int iValueIndex = 0;
                                    int jValueIndex = 1;

                                    // If the Reading Format is by ColumnByColumn 
                                    if (CurTaskNode.ReadFormat == "ColumnbyColumn")
                                    {
                                        minCol = 0;
                                        int lengthHeader = 0;
                                        if (CurTaskNode.ReadHeader == true)
                                        {
                                            lengthHeader = CurTaskNode.HEADER_MAX_ROW - CurTaskNode.HEADER_MIN_ROW;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            lengthHeader = CurTaskNode.HeaderData.Length;

                                        }
                                        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < lengthHeader; iCol++)
                                        {

                                            // Checking whether the Header data exists or not
                                            if (CurTaskNode.HeaderData[minCol] != "")
                                            {
                                                //if (!(excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol]).Locked)
                                                //{

                                                // Assigning the Value from reader to the particular cell in excel sheet

                                                        excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol] = values[iValueIndex];
                                                        iValueIndex++;

                                                //}

                                            }
                                            minCol++;
                                        }
                                        minRow++;
                                    }
```

In the code, writing to excel cell is

excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol] = values[iValueIndex];

here I have to check the condition whether the cell is locked or not, I tried it, but this is not correct.

CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW is the minrow value for that data to write in excel sheet, this value comes from XML file and if I have to write from (10, 2) to (20, 10) , cells, in which if the first cell is say locked, I cant write it to that cell and I have to proceed writing with other cells.

Please help me in doing this. Thanks, Ramm

Answer (score 2):

((Range)excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol]).Locked is the property to find a cells locked attribute.

excelworksheet.Protection.AllowBlahBlahBlah is the property to get/set a kind of protection  for a worksheet.

excelworksheet.ProtectionMode is a read only boolean to find out if the protection defined by the AllowBlahBlahBlah's is enabled.

So I might use

```
Range r = (Range)excelworksheet.Cells[CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol]?? new Range(); // cover null
    if(
    r.Locked && // is cell locked
    excelworksheet.ProtectionMode && // is sheet protected
    !excelworksheet.Protection.AllowFormattingCells) // are locked cells not allowed to be messed with
        DoSomethingBecauseItsProtected();
```

Comment: Hi,
excelworksheet.Range(CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_ROW + minRow, CurTaskNode.DATA_MIN_COL + minCol).Locked 

itself is invalid statement, since I cant use .Locked for this type.
is it we need to declare object for it initially and later check whehter its locked  or not>
Please help me in doin this
THanks 
Ramm

Comment: I made changes.  You're right, you first need to cast the Cells object to range to get at the locked property.